# What classes/interfaces should every .NET developer know?

Tags: .net, class

I just saw an interview with Luca Bolognese from the MS language team, and he mentioned that Anders Hejlsberg thinks developers should focus more on the BCL (base class library, framework) instead of lanugage features (C#, VB.NET).

Which class or interface in the current .net 3.5 framework should every developer know?

Comment: I am thinking of something like:  Make sure you know System.Transactions.TransactionScope if you are working with databases

Comment: This question is a bit ridiculous. It's going to end up being a list of all the classes in the .NET framework - because what's important to one person is meaningless to the next.

Comment: Yes I see ... I wait another day and see where the answers tend to go to... Maybe I specify a new question with a more precise topic

Comment: Some classes and interfaces in the framework are important to everyone. IDisposable is a good example.

Comment: Please vote for close this question. thanks

Answer (score 9):

IDisposable and most of System.Collections.Generic spring to mind...

Answer (score 8):

`System.IO.Path`. Really.

Comment: debatable - System.Web is more important to me

Comment: System.Web is known to anyone who wants to do Web with .NET and not knowing it won't harm you. But System.IO.Path is typically unknown to many people, so they write their own path string handling routines, which usually results in broken software. Therefore I consider System.IO.Path an important class for every developer, in contrast to System.Web classes. And the author asked for specific classes, not huge namespaces.

Answer (score 5):

Not 3.5 specific, but I would suggest two classes that gives for free what many writes code to solve: [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) (OregonGhost beat me by a few seconds on that one...) and [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx). One underused gem in here is the method [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

And also [`EventHandler<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx), instead of defining your own event delegates.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on WHAT you want to develop. I think most of us only (and only needs to) know parts of the whole framework.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a class, but if you're talking about 3.5 framework essentials then IQueryable is important to know.

Comment: +1: I change my question to classes and interfaces

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about .NET 3.5 specific classes, The **LINQ** extension methods in the static **Enumerable** class are (IMHO) the most important.

Comment: The funny thing with that is that the class Enumerable itself isn't really important, since many developers won't even know they're using it :D

Answer (score 2):

System.String?

Comment: +1: but I am not looking for the base types :-)

Answer (score 2):

The classes in System.Reflection and System.Diagnostics are quite powerful pieces of the framework that nobody seems to know.

Comment: I am looking more for specific classes

Answer (score 2):

[System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)... all your classes inherited from it.

Comment: +1. HAHA ... Not what I was looking for, but you are so right!

Answer (score 0):

System.Int32